# Row copy with transformation using formulas

Tags: google-sheets

Sample [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A-Ba1hlB44BSJffQ_0iL3jNR7_MfWG6PQV7nNVQme2M/edit#gid=199780527) linked.

Have table as;

```
fromDate    toDate      Data
2018-01-01  2018-01-05  A
2018-02-01  2018-02-03  B
... so on
```

Need to change/transform to the following form where each day in date range has been converted to a row.

```
Date        Data
2018-01-01  A
2018-01-02  A
2018-01-03  A
2018-01-04  A
2018-01-05  A
2018-02-01  B
2018-02-02  B
2018-02-03  B
... so on
```

Is this possible using formulas?

EDIT 1 ; added Sheets custom function to accomplish the same. again, could this be done using built-in formulae?

```
function DateRangeToRows(values) {
  var new_values=[];
  for (var r=0; r<values.length; r++) {
    var stt=values[r][0], end=values[r][1];
    while (stt<=end) {
      new_values.push([new Date(stt)].concat(values[r].slice(2)));
      stt.setDate(stt.getDate()+1);
    }
  }
  return new_values;
}
```

Comment: Can there be overlaps between successive date ranges?

Comment: Yes there could be overlaps

Comment: Yes it is possible using formulas.

Comment: Any hints? Which functions should I look at, side from Arrayformula ?

Comment: Any hints which functions I should use aside from Arrayformula?

Comment: It's quite tricky, needing multiple split join and transpose. I will post something that shows a possible method but still needs some refinement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to build a 2d array where each row is the different days in the date range, then split it out into separate rows, but at the moment I'm hard-coding the maximum length of the date range as 10 just to test it

```
=ArrayFormula(split(transpose(split(textjoin("#",true,if((transpose(row(1:10))+A2:A3-1)>B2:B3,"",transpose(row(1:10))+A2:A3-1&"|"&C2:C3)),"#")),"|"))
```

The next step will be to replace the 1:10 with the maximum date range from the data, using Indirect which leads to this:

```
=ArrayFormula(split(transpose(split(textjoin("#",true,if((transpose(row(indirect("1:"&max(B2:B3-A2:A3)+1)))+A2:A3-1)>B2:B3,"",transpose(row(indirect("1:"&max(B2:B3-A2:A3)+1)))+A2:A3-1&"|"&C2:C3)),"#")),"|"))
```

It isn't possible to change the references to full columns (A2:A etc) because it would need the sheet to have extra rows, but you can choose an arbitrary number of rows and select only used rows:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(split(transpose(split(textjoin("#",true,if((transpose(row(indirect("1:"&max(B2:B10-A2:A10)+1)))+A2:A10-1)>B2:B10,"",transpose(row(indirect("1:"&max(B2:B10-A2:A10)+1)))+A2:A10-1&"|"&C2:C10)),"#")),"|"),"select * where Col1>0"))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant work @tom. I'll work to get the ranges with the number of exact rows and use INDIRECT. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! Be interested to know how well it scales to a real example. Might be as well to count the number of expected rows generated e.g. with =sumproduct(B2:B-A2:A)+count(A2:A)

Answer (score 1):

Make a list (series fill) from your first `fromDate` to your last `toDate`, lookup their corresponding `Data` values and delete rows where the latter do not exist.