# Google Sheets - Generate n rows in Sheet A based on a value in column from Sheet B

Tags: mysql, excel, database, google-sheets

I have the following data in Sheet A:

```
SheetA
ID | QUANTITY
------------
1  | 3
2  | 2
```

I need a function/formula to generate a unique record in Sheet B based on the number in the QUANTITY column in Sheet A:

```
SheetB
ID | Ref No.
------------
1  | UniqueRecord1_ID1
1  | UniqueRecord2_ID1
1  | UniqueRecord3_ID1
2  | UniqueRecord1_ID2
2  | UniqueRecord2_ID2
```

i.e. I need to generate Sheet B with the same number of rows as the quantity in A with an ascending ref no. on each row.

**PROJECT**

I am a volunteer director at a church and I am building a roster of vacant volunteer positions on our campus. I have an active roster (list of volunteers) that currently serve on our campus. I want to create a new roster of active volunteers AND vacant positions by joining the list of active volunteers and OPEN volunteer positions.

Each volunteer record (row) needs to filter on the following attributes:

```
Attributes 
------------
1  | VolunteerType: Volunteer, Leader, Coordinator 
2  | VolunteerDay: SAT PM, SUN AM, MON PM
3  | VolunteerWeek: Every Week, A Week, B Week
4  | VolunteerTeam: Team1, Team2, Team3 ... (35 different teams)
```

*VolunteerTeam - Different volunteer areas that our volunteers teams can serve on (i.e. greeters, ushers, parking, etc).

Any suggestions on how to approach this project will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like a job for a proper database. Spreadsheets have very limited query-like functionality.

Comment: @pnuts, I am not choosing tags with a random number generator.

Comment: @cdhowie I completely understand that. I have limited knowledge about mysql, but if that's the next level that my be the route I take. I also want to keep it in Google Sheets just because my colleagues are not too tech savy, but they can update records in google sheets relatively easy.

Comment: @JohnMerkel If you already know that you want to use Google Sheets then this is not Excel nor a database nor mysql. I think that is what the comment about random number generator was. • The thing is the question is too broad if you ask us how to implement something. There is just no answer because that is very opinion based.

Comment: @peh Ah, ok. I understand. I'm new at this. Thanks for the tip. I'm open to building on another database platform, that's why I included the extra tags. Just looking for a viable solution for this project.

Comment: My be able to use similar approach to this recent question to get repeating rows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675954/row-copy-with-transformation-using-formulas/50685795?noredirect=1#comment88400486_50685795

Comment: @JohnMerkel Well, as cdhowie already pointed out in comment 2 is that this would at best be a job for a proper database. Now there are at least 100+ database systems out there I guess. Which one to use (or if you decide to stick to Google Sheets) depends highly on your personal interest in how professional that project should be and how much effort you are willing to put in. If you ask 100 people about what to do you will get 100 different opinions which way would be the best. Everyone has his own favorite. This is why you won't get a final answer here.

Comment: @JohnMerkel It might be more a question for a forum where you can discuss different ways and their pros and cons. This site is more like precise question precise answer (less discussions).

Comment: @peh Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as the unique ID's go, you could get them like this

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(textjoin("#",true,if((transpose(row(indirect("1:"&max('Sheet A'!B2:B10)))))>'Sheet A'!B2:B10,"",
"UniqueRecord"&transpose((row(indirect("1:"&max('Sheet A'!B2:B10)))))&"_ID"&'Sheet A'!A2:A10)),"#")))
```

with the ranges adjusted as necessary.